# ON clause condition versus WHERE clause condition WITH JOIN in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

How should we determine which conditions to place in ON clause and which of them to place in WHERE clause in a mysql query. And which of them execute faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time is the same thing as Mysql Query Optimizer does the internal optimization and joins are basically extra conditions. You can also benchmark or use EXPLAIN/DESCRIBE to see how the query is actually executed and what is the [query execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html).

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same.

- Use WHERE clause to **FILTER** records.
- Use JOIN...ON clause to query data from several tables or views; the ON keyword is used to **BIND** tables together. This clause is used when one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many relation is used.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when you are joining tables using `WHERE` clause, MySQL will join them with the general join algorithm. If you need to do `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` or any other type of join, you need to define it explictly.